# Class Static Function Overriding results in Error

Tags: typescript

I have the following code which simply returns an error.

```
class Foo {
    public static logBar<T>(a: T): T {
        console.log(a);
        return a
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public static logBar<T extends number>(a: T): T {
        console.log(a);
        return a
    }
}
```

```
Class static side 'typeof Bar' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Foo'.
   Types of property 'logBar' are incompatible.
     Type '<T extends number>(a: T) => T' is not assignable to type '<T>(a: T) => T'.
       Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
         Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2417)
```

initially i though this was a generics error but i was able to repeat this with the following

```
class Foo {
    public static logBar(a: string): string {
        console.log(a);
        return a
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public static logBar(a: number): number {
        console.log(a);
        return a
    }
}
```

```
Class static side 'typeof Bar' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Foo'.
  Types of property 'logBar' are incompatible.
    Type '(a: number) => number' is not assignable to type '(a: string) => string'.
      Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2417)
```

Is static function with different parameters not overloadable in typescript? if so why other languages do this all the time. examples in the comments.

please note that the following does work

```
class Foo {
    public static logBar(a: string): string {
        console.log(a + 'Foo');
        return a
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public static logBar(a: string): string {
        console.log(a + 'Bar');
        return a
    }
}


Foo.logBar('hello');
Bar.logBar('world');
```

and results with

```
helloFoo
worldBar
```

Answer (score 1):

An instance of a child class should be able to be used whenever an instance of the base class is used. This is called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and it asks the methods of the children classes to accept as input all the values accepted by the same method of the base class as input (and possibly more) and to not return values that the same method of the base class cannot return. The same principle also prevents a child class to restrict the visibility of a property inherited from the base class (if it is `public` in the base class it cannot be changed to `protected` or `private` in the child class; only the other way around is allowed).

The static method `Foo.logBar()` can be invoked with a parameter of type `string`, for example, because there isn't any restriction on the generic parameter `T`.

But `Foo` cannot be replaced with `Bar` in the expression `Foo.logBar('abc')` because `'abc'` is a string and `Bar.logBar()` expects an argument of type `number` (due to `<T extends number>` in the definition of method `logBar()` in class `Bar`).

This is, in plain English, what the error message you quoted tries to tell you.
`T` on the base class can be anything but not all values that it accepts in the base class are accepted for it in the child class; the child class accepts only `number` for `T`.

Comment: what you are saying makes perfect sense for member functions. but what I am talking about is static functions. you are simply speaking about polymorphism. static functions are not polymorphic or at least they should not be.

Comment: here is an example i wrote in c++ really quicly that works. which is along the same lines as the function above. [code](https://gist.github.com/ZNackasha/f694adb36d3d88ad01bfe9c0d7beb356)

Comment: The JavaScript classes are, in fact, functions and the JavaScript functions are objects. This means that the "static" TypeScript methods are, in fact, object properties, therefore instance methods. The JavaScript children classes keep a reference to their parent class; this is how they inherit the properties of the parent class and this is why LSP is probably implemented for the static methods too. Different languages, different ways to implement OOP.

Comment: i made an example in C# that does what i am talking. [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/ZNackasha/b14abe97036e32cc963f7f5e7fc18aee) you can compile and see that it works using https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: C# is not TypeScript even if they are both from Microsoft (and C# was a source of inspiration for the creators of TypeScript) :-) I know the TypeScript compiler is annoying sometimes but it is right more than I like to admit. It protects you from running into errors that could be more difficult to detect at runtime.

Comment: but this comes back to the point that javascript supports overriding why does typescript have an issue?

Comment: JavaScript supports anything, be it correct or not. This is why TypeScript has been invented, I think. To prevent as much as possible to shoot yourself in the foot. At the end of the day, the TypeScript compiler generates JavaScript code you could write by hand as well, except that it prevents you to write many types of code that will hurt you later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting ES6 or newer, then this is probably due to the fact that the TS compiler generates ES classes to match your TypeScript ones. And according to [this blog post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3300-static-methods-are-inherited-when-using-es6-extends-syntax-in-javascript-and-node-js.htm), ES6 classes inherit static members when extending another classes. Due to this behavior, TS must enforce type compatibility between static members to prevent possible runtime type confusion.

TS overloading and overriding come with a lot of caveats in comparison with other object oriented languages. In a language like C# or Java (not script), your example types above would be completely valid. `Foo` would have one static method `logBar` which returns a `string`, and `Bar` would have two static methods - the original `logBar` and an overload which returns a `number`. In TS, **this is not possible because JavaScript does not support overloading**. There can only be one method per property name per object, irregardless of type. Method overloads in TS are only possible because they only exist at compile time. The compiler deletes the overload definitions and only the implementation is emitted to JS. TS does not allow duplicate implementations of an overload. Because the original `logBar` is inherited, there are essentially two conflicting implementations of the same method. I believe that you would see the same error even if the methods were not static.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect you comment. Static function are inherited but that does not mean that they are not overridable.

Comment: In that case, I think the problem is simply that you are trying to override `logBar` with a function that returns an incompatible return type. Even with a normal method, you cannot override a method that returns `string` with one that returns `number`. If you change `Foo.logBar` to return `string | number`, does the error disappear?

Comment: nope still the same issue [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQQAuYFp0I8A5gEJgBOAFGAFzkWvEA7BgEoelfkJQZsM6MHgCI8EAFMAdPQadhAbmmysrFRTysB0MPqwBfDLfQZQkGC1bQVADwoqBAExgISGiY2PhEtJTUtJqunDwCeAC2BCqsorwSDFIhBvKKyuqa2no5skYmZtAA5GBVVtD29hgA9M3QAMLgULxRZBDEvirVFACeOCrwAGbQrlXQgvKsRsAUICPuXj7+0ASQQ07dkTR9A0NVo+NTcIhVai1tWAAqYyowVzis8OOso9UxbHM2EMFvBEjgokR1PdZM9xtUADyPDbePwwBLJVIAPji0EewmgAF5Mbi5sQ0fAKBYoMQGAIwJDoBQkBczojsdxcfiiSS7uhWgZcS83tNwawwIljKkYDVAX5qrULEZ5gJ5GCIapefyBYK4VVHqTyZTnDS6QymYyXtV0SlWLd2AAmAAsAEYAOzCIA)

Comment: I updated my response with some additional information that may help. Essentially, you are overloading `logBar` with incompatible types which is not allowed in TypeScript. It does not matter that the methods are static, because they are inherited.

Comment: i think the overloading you are talking about is different then what i am talking about. you are speaking about using polymorphism i am speaking about static functions. i made an example in C# that does what i am talking. [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/ZNackasha/b14abe97036e32cc963f7f5e7fc18aee) you can compile and see that it works using https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing. Static methods in JS / TS are like instance methods in C#. Due to some JS quirks, that C# code cannot be implemented in TS or JS.